# Is there a way to do model binding manually and out of the Asp.Net MVC Core's model binding process?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model-binding

Below code (from Orchard CMS Framework) uses Asp.Net MVC 4 (System.Web.Mvc) model binding capability to "deserialize" an object from a Dictionary and this is not within MVC's model binding process, are there similar classes in Asp.Net Core to achieve the same:

```
public T TryGetModel<T>(string key) where T : class {
        var binder = new DefaultModelBinder();
        var controllerContext = new ControllerContext();
        var context = new ModelBindingContext {
            ModelMetadata = ModelMetadataProviders.Current.GetMetadataForType(null, typeof(T)),
            ModelName = key,
            ValueProvider = new DictionaryValueProvider<string>(this, null)
        };
        return (T)binder.BindModel(controllerContext, context);

    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure if  you are looking for [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.trygetvalue?view=net-6.0),The document show it applies to `.Net core`

Comment: @XinranShen it is different, I am not interesting the individual value stored in the Dictionary, in fact, the all values of the Dictionary represents a value of T in "my" code.

Comment: sorry boro, I don't find similar class in asp.net core.